# Cross Object Email Alert using Workflow

Tags: workflow, email-alert

I have a custom object called Employee__c which contains an custom email field Email_1__c and also this object is one of the Parent to a Junction Object called Joemp__c.

I have an custom picklist field on Joemp__c which has a value of "Offered".

I am trying to write a workflow in such a way that when my picklist field on Joemp__c value is "Offered", I wanted to send an email to the record email id which is in Employee__c .

I could write a workflow but was not getting to add an action of sending an email to the record email that existed in Parent Object(Employee__c ).

Can you help me please.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've gotta grab the Employee email when you create Joemp__c record - that's the only way a Workflow on the Joemp__c object will be able to send an email to the Employee's email address.

1. Create an email field on Joemp__c object, called Employee_Email__c.
2. Set a workflow on the child Joemp__c object. Whenever a Joemp__c record is created, pull the parent Employee__r.Employee_Email__c field into the Joemp__c.Employee_Email__c field.
3. Then use Joemp__c.Employee_Email__c field in your email alert.

Comment: You saved my life today!